# How to get node current user in an angular view

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sails.js

I'm using a sails.js backend, authenticating using passport, and an angular.js frontend. My app allows users to log in and their information is saved. Right now I can get a list of those users via $http in an angular controller and display them in a view. However, I am completely stumped on getting just the current user. I'm pretty new to this kind of programming and nothing online thus far is really helping me understand what it is I need to do. Can anyone provide an example or tell me what needs to be done to retrieve just the current, logged in user, rather than ALL of the users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In api/controllers/UserController.js. This sails function returns the current user information in req.user.

```
   module.exports = {
     getUser: function(req,res) {
       return res.send(req.user);
};
```

In config/routes.js. This is the route to the 'getUser' function in UserController.js.

```
'/getUser': {
   controller: 'UserController',
   action: 'getUser'
}
```

In assets/js/controllers.js, here is the $http request to the 'getUser' function in UserController.js. This is how you get the information from req.user into the front end.

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
  controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
   $http.get("http://localhost:1337/user/getUser").then(function(result) { 
     $scope.currentUser = result.data;
  })
}]);
```

In assets/js/app.js, make sure your angular route is set to your view.

```
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view', {templateUrl: 'partials/view.html', controller: 'myCtrl'});
}]);
```

After putting this code (with your own variables/routes/server info) in the correct places, you can access the current user in your view like this

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
   {{ currentUser.email }} <br>
   {{ currentUser.username }} <br>
   {{ currentUser.etc }}
 </div>
```

I searched the internet high and low for a week for an answer on how to do this and eventually came up with this. I see that a lot of people (on this site especially) have asked the same question, and I never really found a good, explicit answer. So I thought I would post what I've come up with as an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 3):

Once you authenticate a user via Passport, it saves the current user into the `request` object as `request.user`.

You could create an endpoint in your API that returns that object, then fetch that with Angular.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm using a sails backend, not express. I understand that the information is stored in req.user. I just have no idea how I can get what's in req.user inside my angular.js controller to use in a view.

Comment: Ah, apologies. If you have a controller designated for auth or users, you could create an endpoint in there that does this. Something like `/me`. The syntax would be almost the same - you're still creating a function that takes a `request` and a `response`, and you'd simply send the `request.user` to the front end. As for Angular - are you using an auth framework with it?

Comment: I do have an AuthController.js on the backend. What is /me exactly? I've seen and read about it a lot but I don't get much of an explanation. Also, once written, how would the function SEND req.user to the front end? And I'm not aware of an auth framework for angular. Should I be?